# What's the meaning of setting delegate to nil?

Tags: ios, swift

I found that some programmers will set `someController.delegate = nil` in the `deinit` method of a view controller acting as the delegate of `someController`.

What's the meaning of it? What kind of error it can potentially avoid? Is delegate considered as a strong reference?

Comment: Probably a habit from older objective-c, before the `weak` attribute existed which meant you had to manually nil out references to yourself from objects with longer lifetimes.  I can't think of any reason you would want to do that in swift.

Comment: Except that Objective-C has assign properties, which maps to `unowned` in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's (an outdated way) to avoid a retain cycle. If the class holds a strong reference to an object, and the object holds a strong reference to the class via a delegate, they will never get deallocated. Something like:

```
protocol MyDelegate {
}

class MyClass: MyDelegate {
    // A STRONG REFERENCE TO ANOTHERCLASS
    var someProperty: AnotherClass
    ...
    someProperty.delegate = self
}

class AnotherClass {
    // A STRONG REFERENCE TO MYCLASS (since MyClass is the MyDelegate)
    var delegate: MyDelegate
}
```

As you can see `MyClass` retains `someProperty`. And `someProperty` retains its delegate, which we set as `MyClass`

If they retain each other that creates a memory leak.

Nowadays this is easily solvable by using the weak keyword on delegates (as is recommended). Something like:

```
// need to use :class on the delegate to allow for it to be marked as weak
protocol MyDelegate: class {
}

class MyClass: MyDelegate {
    var someProperty: AnotherClass
    ...
    someProperty.delegate = self
}

class AnotherClass {
    // it is recommended to mark delegates as weak
    weak var delegate: MyDelegate?
}
```

which automatically makes the connection from `AnotherClass` to `MyClass` a weak connection that won't retain if `MyClass` gets deallocated.

So I wouldn't recommend setting delegate = nil in dealloc, instead follow the weak delegate convention.